# Does Aurelia support transclusion?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm familiar with the concept of `ngTransclude` via [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) and `this.props.children` via [ReactJs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html), however does Aurelia support transclusion, that is, the notion of inserting, or transcluding, arbitrary content into another component?

---

### Transclusion in AngularJS (https://plnkr.co/edit/i3STs2MjPrLhIDL5eANg)

**HTML**

```
<some-component>
  Hello world
</some-component>
```

**JS**

```
app.directive('someComponent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: `<div style="border: 1px solid red">
                  <div ng-transclude>
               </div>`
  }
})
```

**RESULT**

[image: result]

---

### Transclusion in ReactJs (https://plnkr.co/edit/wDHkvVJR3FL09xvnCeHE)

**JS**

```
const Main = (props) => (
    <SomeComonent>
      hello world
    </SomeComonent>
);

const SomeComonent = ({children}) => (
    <div style={{border: '1px solid red'}}> 
      {children}
    </div>
);
```

**RESULT**

[image: result]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several ways to do transclusion: **[Official docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-content-projection/1)**

## 1. content slot `<slot></slot>`

The `<slot>` element serves as a placeholder in a component's template for arbitrary content. Example:

**some-component.html**

```html
<template>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

**usage:**

```html
<template>
  <require from="some-component"></require>

  <some-component>
    hello world
  </some-component>
</template>
```

**result:**
[image: result]

## 2. named slots

A component can contain several replaceable parts. The user of the component can replace some or all of the parts. Parts that aren't replaced will display their default content.

**blog-post.html**

```html
<template>
  <h1>
    <slot name="header">
      Default Title
    </slot>
  </h1>
  <article>
    <slot name="content">
      Default content
    </slot>
  </article>
  <div class="footer">
    <slot name="footer">
      Default footer
    </slot> 
  </div>
</template>
```

**usage:**

```html
<template>
  <require from="blog-post"></require>

  <blog-post>
    <template slot="header">
      My custom header
    </template>
    <template slot="content">
      My custom content lorem ipsum fla fla fla
    </template>
    <template slot="footer">
      Copyright Megacorp
    </template> 
  </blog-post>
</template>
```

## 3. template parts

The slots spec has limitations: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-content-projection/5

Use template-parts for dynamically generated slots: https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/432

Comment: Trap for young players: you can't use `<content>` to fill in `<option>`s in a `<select>` - see https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/304 - this had me stumped for quite a while before I opened that issue and Rob cleared it up for me.

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated, according to the [docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-custom-elements/6) you should use `<slot></slot>` instead of `<content></content>`

Comment: It looks like `<template slot="slot-name">Content</template>` is not working, instead you should use a `div` or something. It's also described in the Aurelia docs that way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Aurelia supports the concept of transclusion through use of the `<content />` component. Per the below, any content nested within `<some-component>` be it HTML, a String, or another component, will be rendered within this component.

**app.js**

```
export class App {}
```

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="some-component"></require>
  <some-component>
    hello world
  </some-component>
</template>
```

**some-component.js**

```
export class SomeComponent {}
```

**some-component.html**

```
<template>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red">
    <content />
  </div>
</template>
```

**RESULT**

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: USE SLOT INSTEAD OF CONTENT**

```
// Actual component
<your-component>
  Just some content
</your-component>

// Template of the component
<template>
  <div class="some-styling">
    <slot></slot> // <-- "Just some content" will be here!!
  </div>
</template>
```